# Plot with two x-axis and one y-axis or nyquistplot with Frequency on second x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

My goal is it to plot data in a coordinate system with one y-axis and two x-axis.

right now I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}    

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{
blue!01!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=none\\
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist2}{
blue!70!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=none\\
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\large}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both, 
axis equal,
width=12cm, 
height=9cm,
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,    
xlabel={x1}, ylabel={y1}, 
legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east, cells={anchor=west}},
legend style={font=\footnotesize},
cycle list name=mycolorlist,
]
\addplot [] coordinates {(2.72E+03,-4.55E+02)(4.68E+03,-1.19E+03)(1.14E+04,-3.17E+03)};
\legend{Zyklus 0}
\end{axis}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
width=12cm,
height=9cm,
cycle list name=mycolorlist2,
axis x line*=top,
xlabel={x2}     
]
\addplot coordinates {(1.26E+07,-4.55E+02) (2.00E+05,-1.19E+03)(2.00E+02,-3.17E+03)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]

I plotted the values for x1 (x-Axis on the bottom) against the values for y1 and also x2 (top) against y1. So there are two problems.

**First:**
There should only be numbers for x1 against y1 on the y-axis. So how can I "delete" the others?

**Second:**
**I have to use** `axis equal` for x1 against y1 but this leads to the shift between the two lines. In a proper code they should have the same start and end-point (they do if you remove `axis equal`, but it's disallowed).

Here is some of the data from `mydata.txt`:

```
x1|              y1|               x2

2,72E+03|        -4,55E+02|        1,26E+07

4,68E+03|        -1,19E+03|        2,00E+05

1,14E+04|        -3,17E+03|        2,00E+02
```

I just used "|" as a separator of the columns.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of using files that we don't have, could you modify the code to use just a couple of specific coordinates. E.g. `\addplot coordinates {(0,0)(2,2)};` instead of `\addplot table ...`. For example, use the start and end point of each plot. Makes it a lot easier to test.

Comment: I edited the code and used `\addplot coordinates {(x1,y1)(x1,y1)(x1,y1)}` for x1(bottom) against y1 and `\addplot coordinates {(x2,y1)(x2,y1)(x2,y1)}` for x2(top) vs y1. The data is from the table in the question. **Result:** They now have the same start and ending-point. That's how it's supposed to be, but there is still a shift when using my data (like in the image I attached to this question). If you run the edited code you'll only see that the "first" problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I forgot to revisit this one. It's a bit hard to say if this helps, as your example only reproduces one of the problems. If you figured it our yourself, considering posting an answer yourself.

Anyway:

1. Add `axis y line=none` on the second axis. Or possibly `axis y line=right`, to place those numbers on the right side of the axis. Another possibility is `ytick=\empty` for the second axis.
2. I can't test this, so it's a shot in the dark, but perhaps it helps to set `enlarge x limits` explicitly for both axes. I.e. something like `enlarge x limits=0.1`, or `enlarge x limits={abs=5mm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}    

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{
blue!01!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=none\\
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist2}{
blue!70!green,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!10!black},mark=none\\
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\large}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both, 
axis equal,
width=12cm, 
height=9cm,
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,    
xlabel={x1}, ylabel={y1}, 
legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east, cells={anchor=west}},
legend style={font=\footnotesize},
cycle list name=mycolorlist,
enlarge x limits=0.1
]
\addplot [] coordinates {(2.72E+03,-4.55E+02)(4.68E+03,-1.19E+03)(1.14E+04,-3.17E+03)};
\legend{Zyklus 0}
\end{axis}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
width=12cm,
height=9cm,
cycle list name=mycolorlist2,
axis x line*=top,
axis y line=none,% or right
enlarge x limits=0.1,
xlabel={x2}     
]
\addplot coordinates {(1.26E+07,-4.55E+02) (2.00E+05,-1.19E+03)(2.00E+02,-3.17E+03)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bodegraph package - http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/bodegraph/bodegraph.pdf (see page 15 to the end)

doc in french